# Custom Button initWithImage displaying a default button behind the custom image

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I am trying to make a button for my navigation bar with a custom image. When I run the following code, the button appears as it should, except you can see another wider button behind it, sticking out the sides. How do I get rid of that other button?

```
UIBarButtonItem *emailButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"emailBut"]
                                                                style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose
                                                               target:self 
                                                               action:@selector(emailSheet)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = emailButton;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for some reason initWithImage only puts the image in the center of a default button. The fix was to initWithCustomView as iBlue suggested.

Another thing to note is that the barBackButton doesn't allow custom views, so I had to make that one a leftButton instead of a backButton, with my own go back method. I hope Apple makes this easier in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... `UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose` is a system icon, so I guess you are probably overlaying your icon on top of it. You should instead use `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` (or other styles) for your `style:` argument.

**Edit:**

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
[button setBackgroundImage:someImage];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(something:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
```

Comment: I tried changing it to plain and bordered, the button behind the image was still there, with the same size, only a different color.

Comment: If you are referring to that border, you should use `UIButton` instead of `UIBarButtonItem`.